# build unsuccessful in android studio

Tags: android

Hello I have a problem that I am experiencing when compiling my android application. It displays the error below. How can I solve the problem

```
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionSnapshotImpl 
cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `{project dir}/.gradle/{version}.`

Sync Project with Gradle File

Comment: please elaborate more i didnt understand the tag, but iam in the project directory whould i delete the file insde .gradle , the file with 2.1.0 or something else

Comment: Yes, delete the folder 2.1.0. Then got to android studio, Click tools-> Android ->Sync project with gradle file. Then clean, build your project

Comment: Thank you so much, you dont know how much u have saved me.

Comment: Great, Please up vote and accept the answer if it helps you.